# Life time of a wave

Tags: quantum-field-theory

Let us consider, we have guessed a potential for a wave like non linear, which is propagating through space. 
We guess a Lagrangian for the wave 
$$L= \int r^{d-1} dr \left[\frac{1}{2}\dot \phi^2 -\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\partial \phi}{ \partial r}\right)^2- V \right]$$
The lagtrangian is due to Minkowski-space time dimensions.

IF we know the total energy from the wave equation of the lagrangian then how can we get the decay rate of the wave?

Answer (score 1):

I assume what you have in mind is a thought experiment in which you ping the system with a band-limited impulse (throw a pebble into the water).  Then there are at least 3 things that contribute to measurable "decay" of the pulse.  Elastic scattering and geometrical spreading are reversible and energy conserving.  So even neglecting stuff like viscosity, unless you are in 1D, spreading will cause the pulse to decay.  In the presence of viscosity or other irreversible losses (i.e., in the real world), there will be additional decay terms.  Operationally, you would monitor the pulse as it propagates and look at the decay of the envelope.  It's possible to estimate the same decay rate with a CW type source but we'll leave it as a pulse.  The standard definition of the decay length assumes an exponential decrease with time or distance of the pulse: then arbitrarily we say the 1/e (or e-folding) length is the decay length or the decay time.

The total energy of the solution obviously depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: @Raisa Note that (in view of the your tag "quantum-field-theory") irreversible losses and dissipation need a special treatment: you can't just naively add dissipation terms, because the wave will dissapear, leading to violation of the Heisenberg inequality. Another way of looking at this is that total probability ($\mathbf{L}^2$ norm of $\phi$) has to stay equal to unity - the system has to wind up _somewhere_ in state space! So you need to add quantum basis states representing excitations of the surrounding environment to your description for the wave to decay into.

Comment: Absolutely.  I was answering thee question not the tag.  In general you would include the environment in which the "wave" was embedded.  But that's true in the classical case too if you want to conserve energy.